# Do d3 elements need to be redefined with repeated code?

Tags: d3.js

I'm pretty new to D3, but all the examples I've seen redefine the creation of an element when it's updated. I can see an argument for that if you want to change the way the element is defined (e.g. change a circle to a rectangle), but in most case I've needed the definition is identical.

This example is a merge of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45167926/1835727) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33809812/1835727) answer. It's closer to my actual use case, but it also highlights the amount of duplicaiton.

Hopefully I'm way off base in the way I've defined this and there is a much tidier way to do it. Alternatively, I guess the answer is "*yes, this is the ideomatic way of doing it*".

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
d3.select("button").on("click", update);
let color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemeAccent);
let data;
update();

function update() {
  updateData();
  updateNodes();
}

function updateData() {
  let numNodes = ~~(Math.random() * 4 + 10);
  data = d3.range(numNodes).map(function(d) {
    return {
      size: ~~(Math.random() * 20 + 3),
      x: ~~(Math.random() * 600),
      y: ~~(Math.random() * 200)
    };
  });
}

function updateNodes() {
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node").data(data);
  node.exit().remove();
  node
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .classed("node", true)
    .append("circle")
    .classed("outer", true)
    .attr("fill", d => color(d.size))
    .attr("opacity", 0.5)
    .attr("r", d => d.size * 2)
    .attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y)
    .select(function() { return this.parentNode; }) //needs an old style function for this reason:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371982/what-does-this-refer-to-in-arrow-functions-in-es6 .select(()=> this.parentNode) won't work
    .append("circle")
    .classed("inner", true)
    .attr("fill", d => color(d.size))
    .attr("r", d => d.size)
    .attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y)
    .select(function() { return this.parentNode; })
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", d => d.x)
    .attr("y", d => d.y)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(d => d.size);

  node
    .select("circle.inner")
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("fill", d => color(d.size))
    .attr("r", d => d.size)
    .attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y);

  node
    .select("circle.outer")
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("fill", d => color(d.size))
    .attr("opacity", 0.5)
    .attr("r", d => d.size * 2)
    .attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y);

  node
    .select("text")
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("x", d => d.x)
    .attr("y", d => d.y)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(d => d.size);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<button>Update</button>
<br>
<svg width="600" height="200"></svg>
```

Comment: You don't have any way of determining whether nodes have been updated in your current code, so every update removes all existing data points and replaces them with a new set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is "no, elements do not need to be redefined with repeated code." The longer answer (which I will try to keep short) concerns the d3 enter / update / exit paradigm and object constancy.

There is already a lot of documentation about [d3's data binding paradigm](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#joining-data); by thinking about data bound to DOM elements, we can identify the `enter` selection, new data/elements; the `update` selection, existing data/elements that have changed; and the `exit` selection, data/elements to be deleted. Using a key function to uniquely identify each datum when joining it to the DOM allows d3 to identify whether it is new, updated, or has been removed from the data set. For example:

```
var data = [{size: 8, id: 1}, {size: 10, id: 2}, {size: 24, id: 3}];

var nodes = svg.selectAll(".node").data(data, function (d) { return d.id });

// deal with enter / exit / update selections, etc.

// later on
var updated = [{size: 21, id: 1}, {size: 10, id: 4}, {size: 24, id: 3}];

var nodes_now = svg.selectAll(".node")
.data(updated, function (d) { return d.id });

// nodes_now.enter() will contain {size:10, id: 4}
// nodes_now.exit() will contain {size:10, id: 2}
```

Again, there is a lot of existing information about this; see [the d3 docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#joining-data) and [object constancy](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/) for more details.

If there are no data/elements in the chart being updated--e.g. if the visualisation is only being drawn once and animation is not desired, or if the data is being replaced each time the chart is redrawn, there is no need to do anything with the `update` selection; the appropriate attributes can be set directly on the `enter` selection. In your example, there is no key function so every update dumps all the old data from the chart and redraws it with the new data. You don't really need any of the code following the transformations that you perform on the `enter` selection because there is no `update` selection to work with.

The kinds of examples that you have probably seen are those where the update selection is used to animate the chart. A typical pattern is

```
// bind data to elements
var nodes = d3.selectAll('.node')
.data( my_data, d => d.id )

// delete extinct data
nodes.exit().remove()

// add new data items
var nodeEnter = nodes.enter()
.append(el) // whatever the element is
.classed('node', true)
.attr(...) // initialise attributes

// merge the new nodes into the existing selection to create the enter+update selection
// turn the selection into a transition so that any changes will be animated
var nodeUpdate = nodes
.merge(nodesEnter)
.transition()
.duration(1000)

// now set the appropriate values for attributes, etc.
nodeUpdate
.attr(...)
```

The enter+update selection contains both newly-initialised nodes and existing nodes that have changed value, so any transformations have to cover both these cases. If we wanted to use this pattern on your code, this might be a way to do it:

```
  // use the node size as the key function so we have some data persisting between updates
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node").data(data, d => d.size)

  // fade out extinct nodes
  node
    .exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr('opacity', 0)
    .remove()

  // save the enter selection as `nodeEnter`
  var nodeEnter = node
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .classed("node", true)
    .attr("opacity", 0)    // set initial opacity to 0
    // transform the group element, rather than each bit of the group
    .attr('transform', d => 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')')

  nodeEnter
   .append("circle")
    .classed("outer", true)
    .attr("opacity", 0.5)
    .attr("fill", d => color(d.size))
    .attr("r", 0)                     // initialise radius to 0
  .select(function() { return this.parentNode; })
   .append("circle")
    .classed("inner", true)
    .attr("fill", d => color(d.size))
    .attr("r", 0)                     // initialise radius to 0
  .select(function() { return this.parentNode; })
   .append("text")
    .attr("dy", '0.35em')
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(d => d.size)

 // merge enter selection with update selection
 // the following transformations will apply to new nodes and existing nodes
 node = node
    .merge(nodeEnter)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)

  node
    .attr('opacity', 1)  // fade into view
    .attr('transform', d => 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')')  // move to appropriate location

  node.select("circle.inner")
    .attr("r", d => d.size)      // set radius to appropriate size

  node.select("circle.outer")
    .attr("r", d => d.size * 2)  // set radius to appropriate size
```

Only elements and attributes that are being animated (e.g. the circle radius or the opacity of the `g` element of new nodes) or that rely on aspects of the datum that may change (the `g` transform, which uses `d.x` and `d.y` of existing nodes) need to be updated, hence the update code is far more compact than that for the enter selection.

Full demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
d3.select("button").on("click", update);
let color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemeAccent);
let data;
update();

function update() {
  updateData();
  updateNodes();
}

function updateData() {
  let numNodes = ~~(Math.random() * 4 + 10);
  data = d3.range(numNodes).map(function(d) {
    return {
      size: ~~(Math.random() * 20 + 3),
      x: ~~(Math.random() * 600),
      y: ~~(Math.random() * 200)
    };
  });
}

function updateNodes() {
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node").data(data, d => d.size)
  node
    .exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr('opacity', 0)
    .remove()

  var nodeEnt = node
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .classed("node", true)
    .attr("opacity", 0)
    .attr('transform', d => 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')')
   
  nodeEnt
    .append("circle")
    .classed("outer", true)
    .attr("opacity", 0)
    .attr("fill", d => color(d.size))
    .attr("r", d => 0)
   .select(function() { return this.parentNode; }) //needs an old style function for this reason:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371982/what-does-this-refer-to-in-arrow-functions-in-es6 .select(()=> this.parentNode) won't work
    .append("circle")
    .classed("inner", true)
    .attr("fill", d => color(d.size))
    .attr("r", 0)
   .select(function() { return this.parentNode; })
    .append("text")
    .attr("dy", '0.35em')
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(d => d.size)
    
 node = node
    .merge(nodeEnt)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)

  node
    .attr('opacity', 1)
    .attr('transform', d => 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')')
 
  node.select("circle.inner")
    .attr('opacity', 1)
    .attr("r", d => d.size)

  node
    .select("circle.outer")
    .attr("opacity", 0.5)
    .attr("r", d => d.size * 2)

}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<button>Update</button>
<br>
<svg width="600" height="200"></svg>
```

It is worth noting that there are plenty of d3 examples that have a lot of redundant code in them.

So much for keeping this short...